Capacitor and vanilla JS: Load HTML elements in the main HTML
I'm working on a mobile app with capacitor and vanilla Js and I'm following a tutorial to help me set it [up][1]. In the tutorial, it is indicated that to make several pages of our app, we copy and paste the code in each of the pages (index.html, info.html), but I find that a lot of code is duplicated like the header, footer, etc.
Example of index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    // a lot of header code which we want to import via another source
  </head>
  <body>
    <custom-navbar>
      <h1 slot="title">My capacitor app</h1>
      <div slot="end">
        <a href="/info.html"><button>Info</button></a>
      </div>
    </custom-navbar>
    <script src="./js/navbar.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>

and I'm looking to load the code that looks similar from a single file a bit like PHP's include(‘my_file.php’) ($vars) so as not to duplicate the same code in a page.
For example, in my index I would like the header to be loaded from an external file that I can simply import a bit like the class constructor method import in our main html file of a .custom-header.js file which looks like this
`window.customElements.define(
  'custom-header',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      SplashScreen.hide();
      const root = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      root.innerHTML = `<style>
      :host {
         font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,....";
         display: block;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
  } etc....` 

And import it in the main html file like this:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <custom-header></custom-header>
  <body>
    <custom-navbar>
      <h1 slot="title">My capacitor app</h1>
      <div slot="end">
        <a href="/info.html"><button>Info</button></a>
      </div>
    </custom-navbar>
    <script src="./js/navbar.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>

What I've found so far that works is a javascript import and the document.getelementbyID().innerHTML method as shown here:
const header = `
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    //.. all our header html code
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#31d53d" />
</head>
`
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = header;

and in our index.html put an id where we want to have the header code:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <body>
  <!-- Our specific body code-->
    <script src="./custom-header.js" type="module"></script>   

But I would like to know if there is a way to do this with classes and constructors like the example I mentioned earlier. Thanks
[1]: https://ionic.io/blog/create-powerful-native-mobile-apps-with-capacitor-vanillajs

Yes and no mplungjan, yes I would like an opinion about this situation (Maybe someone would do it differently and I would be interested to see if one can do it with classes and constructors for example) but I am not asking how you see thing globally in the capacitor world. If you were in this sitation, how would you solve the problem.

The reason I mentioned opinions is that questions requesting opinions will be closed. So perhaps rewrite your question to not sound like you are asking for opinions but rather ask how to solve ONE specific problem you have

Me too, but I understand your point of view. I've changed my question to make it more precise. Thanks
